# How to add a simple authentication page for static pages on a static IP

Tags: webserver, authentication, static-ip

[image: Simple authentication for static pages]

I have seen this simple authentication for websites for restricting the number of users who can access the pages.

I host some of my pages on my in-house servers and I just need a simple authentication like this before the user can access to prevent unauthorized access. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This prompt is implemented using HTTP-level authentication, most commonly HTTP *Basic* auth (although some servers use HTTP *Digest*, with an identical prompt but more behind-the-scenes complexity).

Many web servers have HTTP authentication built in – for example, `AuthType Basic` in [Apache httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html), or `auth_basic` in [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/), or `http_auth()` in HAproxy. Alternatively, it can be implemented directly in your web apps by examining the "Authorization:" HTTP header; see [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization).